# Cancel Site Crawl on Abot

Tags: c#, web-crawler, abot

I have a list of domains that are crawled using Abot, the aim is that when it finds an amazon link on one of the sites, it quits, then moves onto the next site. But I can't seem to see who I can exit the page crawl. e.g.

https://github.com/sjdirect/abot

```
static Main(string[] args)
{
    var domains= new List<string> { "http://domain1", "http://domain2" };

    foreach (string domain in domains)
    {
        var config = new CrawlConfiguration
        {
            MaxPagesToCrawl = 100,
            MinCrawlDelayPerDomainMilliSeconds = 3000
        };

        var crawler = new PoliteWebCrawler(config);

        crawler.PageCrawlCompleted += PageCrawlCompleted;
        var uri = new Uri(domain);
        var crawlResult = crawler.Crawl(uri);
    }
}

private static void PageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
{
    var crawledPage = e.CrawledPage;
    var crawlContext = e.CrawlContext;

    var document = crawledPage.AngleSharpHtmlDocument;
    var anchors = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").OfType<IHtmlAnchorElement>();
    var hrefs = anchors.Select(x => x.Href).ToList();

    var regEx= new Regex(@"https?:\/\/(www|smile)\.amazon(\.co\.uk|\.com).*");
    var resultList = hrefs.Where(f => regEx.IsMatch(f)).ToList();

    if (resultList.Any())
    {
        //NEED TO EXIT THE SITE CRAWL HERE
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue - I think - is that you are tying to control the flow of the loop from a void method. I'm not too sure about this library but it would probably be better to base your link finding logic from the crawl result.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that this library performs the page crawl within that event handler, which can only return void. I think I'll go into the source, see what it's doing and then either override it or create a new method.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the following...

```
var myCancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
crawler.CrawlAsync(someUri, myCancellationToken);

private static void PageCrawlCompleted(object sender, PageCrawlCompletedArgs e)
{
    //More performant (since the parsing has already been done by Abot)
    var hasAmazonLinks = e.CrawledPage.ParsedLinks
      .Any(hl => hl.HrefValue.AbsoluteUri
         .ToLower()
         .Contains("amazon.com"));

    if (hasAmazonLinks)
    {
        //LOG SOMETHING BEFORE YOU STOP THE CRAWL!!!!!

        //Option A: Preferred method, Will clear all scheduled pages and cancel any threads that are currently crawling
        myCancellationToken.Cancel();

        //Option B: Same result as option A but no need to do anything with tokens. Not the preferred method. 
        e.CrawlContext.IsCrawlHardStopRequested = true;

        //Option C: Will clear all scheduled pages but will allow any threads that are currently crawling to complete. No cancellation tokens needed. Consider it a soft stop to the crawl.
        e.CrawlContext.IsCrawlStopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PoliteWebCrawler` is designed to start crawling and dig deeper into the website URLs. If you just want to get the content of a URL (for example first page of a website) you can use `PageRequester` which is designed for such jobs.

```
var pageRequester = new PageRequester(new CrawlConfiguration(), new WebContentExtractor());

var crawledPage = await pageRequester.MakeRequestAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
Log.Logger.Information("{result}", new
{
    url = crawledPage.Uri,
    status = Convert.ToInt32(crawledPage.HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode)
});
```

By the way, if you want to stop a crawler during the process, you can use one of these two methods:

```
//1. hard crawl stop
crawlContext.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
//2. soft stop
crawlContext.IsCrawlStopRequested = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to crawl the site until the Amazon URL is found, then exit crawling that site and move onto the next site.